# How do I create a "floating" box?

Tags: javascript, html

Say I have a link, or just a simple word. When "onmouseover", how would I have a small "infobox" pop up above my mouse displaying information? (The information would have to be queried.. but that's step 2) I need to learn how to do step 1 before I handle step 2.

Thanks!

Comment: `position: absolute; float: left;` There are some nice tooltip libraries out there prebuilt.

Comment: @Mike I'm not sure, but wouldn't that put it in the top-left of the screen?

Comment: try this http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: Something like this? http://sixrevisions.com/css/css-only-tooltips/

Comment: Yes! Something like the tool tips!! I'm downloading and reading the source code now.

Comment: +1 @sachleen, I used that plugin last year, it's great for basic utility and doesn't rely on JS/jQuery. (and if you want, you can obviously modify its text with JS/jQuery later on)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean tool tip, use the `title` attribute.

```
<a href="#" title="Does nothing">Link</a>
```

*EDIT:* It works on any elements. All you need to do is hover over the element for a while.

Comment: For clarification: This works on any element, not just `<a>`, so you can use it on i.e. `<span>` to put it on an ordinary word (though you should give some visual clue that that word might be worth pointing the mouse at).